# In Adobe Illustrator, there's a path in an SVG file that shows up when hovering but cannot be selected or modified

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I opened a SVG file in Adobe Illustrator that was made in another program (Inkscape), wanting to save it as a .ai file. There were some line segments that were completely lost, presumably due to incompatibility in formats, that I had to re-draw. But there's also a quite complex shape that shows up in light blue when the mouse cursor is over it when I'm using the selection tool, but otherwise is invisible, and cannot actually be selected. Effectively it's a "ghost path"--it looks as though it has zero stroke and fill, but since I can't select it I can't even check what stroke and fill it has. In the original SVG it was black and visible.

Having to re-make this shape from scratch would be really annoying, and the information is obviously imported because the shape shows properly when hovering over it. I'm wondering how to get it to actually show the rest of the time though.

Comment: If you are asking for a conversion tool, then the question would be off-topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you select the path if you are in artwork view mode (instead of preview mode)?

Comment: @RohitGupta The goal was simply to be able to open and edit the .svg in Illustrator, while re-drawing as little as possible (making it from the start in Illustrator way back when would have been the BEST option, but I didn't have access to an Illustrator license back then). Opening the file worked, and most of the graphical elements were correct, it was just one path that had a problem.

I ended up eventually re-making that shape, I couldn't find a way to make it editable in the time it took me to re-build it myself from editing built-in shapes.